# can't optimize sql with subselect and aggregate function

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema

Orders (100K+ rows)

```
id (primary, auto increment)
order_date (datetime, indexed)
extra index for order (id + order_date)
```

Basket (400K+ rows)

```
id (primary, auto increment)
order_id(int, indexed)
product_id (int, indexed)

extra keys for basket
```

My input is a minimum date and an array of product ids.
I need to get the orders that contain these products, from these orders get the products with their count excluding the input array of products and return the 8 most sold ones (count() desc)

The most ?? optimized sql statement that I could come up with is

```
SELECT new.product_id  
from (
    select product_id AS product_id
    from shop_order_basket 
    where order_id IN (
        select order_id 
        from shop_order_basket 
        join shop_order on shop_order.id = shop_order_basket.order_id 
        where product_id IN (1,2) and entry_datetime > "2016-09-27 00:00:00"
    ) 
    and product_id NOT IN (1,2) 
) as new
group by new.product_id
order by count(new.product_id) desc
limit 8
```

It takes 4secs to execute the query whereas all my other queries are under 0.02s.

I can't find anything wrong using explain - it seems to be using indexes and all execution time is spent on the table that is created (the sql inside the from brackets) - not in the group by.

Can anyone propose another faster method to get the required result or explain where I am wrong in my sql statement and it's taking so much time?

```
id select_type          table              type     possible_keys                   key        key_len    ref   rows    Extra   
1  PRIMARY              <derived2>         ALL      NULL                            NULL       NULL       NULL  2506    Using temporary; Using filesort
2  DERIVED              shop_order_basket  index    product_id                      order_id_2 8          NULL  357289  Using where; Using index
3  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   shop_order_basket  ref      order_id,product_id,order_id_2  order_id   4          func  1       Using where
3  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   shop_order         eq_ref   PRIMARY,entry_datetime,id       PRIMARY    4          func  1       Using where
```

Comment: joins are *probably* faster then sub selects. Worth a try

Comment: @Pevara how would I select the products that are in the same order with the input array of products using a join?

Comment: You can collapse your outer query into your first subquery "new" (although I doubt it will have much effect, and it is probably optimized away anyway). But please add your explain output so we can see for ourselves if there is something wrong.

Comment: if you can provide some sort of fiddle, or a (partial, anonimized) dump of the  database I'll be happy to have a look at it. I'm not going to post some query that I haven't been able to test cause I know it won't work. My SQL isn't that good, and I rarely get my queries right on the first try